# What are the big wart-like bumps on my hibiscus leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, shrubs, hibiscus

The leaves on my Hibiscus bushes have developed big wart-like bumps. They are spreading rapidly and it seems like they are killing my bush.

What are they, and how can I cure them?

Comment: Did you intend to upload a photo? In case you are having trouble doing so, note that the file must be less than 2 Meg.

Comment: Galls? https://www.google.com/search?q=hibiscus+galls&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiylZqNzbvMAhUKFT4KHfASDQEQ_AUICCgC&biw=971&bih=526

Comment: We need the picture to help!

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post for instructions on how to [edit] an image into a post. Thanks!